# Put command string on the bash prompt

Tags: bash, shell, command-prompt, stdin

Say I have bash prompt in the terminal:

```
host:~/dir $
```

how can I write a command to the prompt that the user can choose to run? Maybe there is a way to use readline(3) to put a command in the shell prompt?

In other words, I am looking to write a command here:

```
 host:~/dir $ <write some command here>
```

I tried:

```
echo "write some command here" > /dev/stdin
```

but that didn't quite work - it doesn't seem to put it on the prompt, is there a way to do that?

**What I am trying to do** - When you hit up/down arrow keys with bash, your previous command shows up in the prompt, I am trying to read from another history file and put it on the prompt.

Comment: yeah that was a typo, but after fixing that didn't work, doesn't seem to put it on the prompt

Comment: You should first find the `pts` of the target terminal with `ps`.  Suppose pts is 2 then you could do  `echo "write some command" > /dev/pts/2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280410/how-do-i-edit-the-output-of-a-bash-script-before-executing-it

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about what your use case is, I'd start by pointing you in the direction of whiptail. It's part of the base install of most Linux systems and it allows you to present an input box to the user, even allowing for the box to be pre-filled with a default value. A very simple example would look roughly like this:

```sh
whiptail --input "Want to run this?" 8 78 "<write command here>" --title "Dialog box title here"
```

There's a [primer available on WikiBooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bash_Shell_Scripting/Whiptail) that does an adequate job of introducing most of its basic features, if you want to dive deeper.

Comment: When you hit up/down arrow keys with bash, your previous command shoes up in the prompt, I am trying to read from another history file and put it on the prompt. I will add this to the OP.

Comment: Well when you want to make calls to the history file of the terminal you're using, typically you'd use `!!` for the most recent command, `!-2` for the next to last command, and if you wanted to search for something in particular then `!?somecommand`. You could put those into the <write command here> part of my whiptail example and it would display them for the user.

Is that closer to what you're trying to do?